# robust pylint disable for an option recently introduced

Tags: python, pylint

We have several versions of `pylint` in various stages of our CI system (for good reasons: we want to test that our code works across a range of package versions).

Now, an option `import-outside-toplevel` was introduced as per `pylint=2.4.0` (according to [the changelog](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/changelog.html#what-s-new-in-pylint-2-4-0)).

How do we disable that pylint error in a robust way (or conditional on `pylint>=2.4.0`)?

I have tried:

1. `# pylint: disable=import-outside-toplevel`
2. `# pylint: disable=C0415`
3. No disable.

In case 1 and 2, running pylint version 2.4.3 (on a CI stage aligned with `anaconda=2019.03`) causes `E0012: Bad option value`.  In case 3, running pylint version 2.4.2 (on a CI stage aligned with `anaconda=2019.10`) causes `C0415: Import outside toplevel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, I am disabling the whole `'C'` category for just the scope (in my case, a single line):

```
def blah(...):
    import foo.bar  # pylint: disable=C
```

That works across pylint 2.3 to 2.5, although it isn't as specific as I would like.